# Table Merge Based on Single Column Identifier

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

First time asking question, long time visitor and teaching myself coding out of necessity because Excel doesn't cut it!  That said... please be kind, I am very new at this.

I have two tables 'compare' and 'himsshospital' under schema 'physician_compare'.  Both tables have a column 'CCN1'.  I want to merge the two tables together, using CCN1 is the matching identifier.  There is no primary key in either table.  I want to keep the duplicate values in the 'compare' table, just add columns to the table from the 'himsshospital' table based on CCN1.  In excel, this would be the equivalent of doing a vlookup based on the CCN1 in the 'compare' table and than referencing the 'himsshospital' table and dragging down.  End product would be the 'compare' table with corresponding 'himss hospital' columns added to it matched based on CCN1.

From my forum searching, I think I need to do an inner join, but keep getting errors such as 'Error code: 1146 Table Does Not Exist' or 'Error Code: 1052 Column is Abmiguous'.

Thank you in advance!

This is the query I have tried before, and I included the the table/column setup as well. I am using MySQL Workbench.

```
`use physician_compare;
 select tbl_names.CCN1
 from tbl_names.compare
 inner join tbl_names.himsshospital
 on tbl_names.CCN1=tbl_names.CCN1;`

SELECT `compare`.`NPI`,
`compare`.`PAC ID`,
`compare`.`Professional Enrollment ID`,
`compare`.`Last Name`,
`compare`.`First Name`,
`compare`.`Middle Name`,
`compare`.`Suffix`,
`compare`.`Gender`,
`compare`.`Credential`,
`compare`.`Medical school name`,
`compare`.`Graduation year`,
`compare`.`Primary specialty`,
`compare`.`Secondary specialty 1`,
`compare`.`Secondary specialty 2`,
`compare`.`Secondary specialty 3`,
`compare`.`Secondary specialty 4`,
`compare`.`All secondary specialties`,
`compare`.`Organization legal name`,
`compare`.`Group Practice PAC ID`,
`compare`.`Number of Group Practice members`,
`compare`.`Line 1 Street Address`,
`compare`.`Line 2 Street Address`,
`compare`.`Marker of address line 2 suppression`,
`compare`.`City`,
`compare`.`State`,
`compare`.`Zip Code`,
`compare`.`Phone Number`,
`compare`.`CCN1`,
`compare`.`Hospital affiliation LBN 1`,
`compare`.`Hospital affiliation CCN 2`,
`compare`.`Hospital affiliation LBN 2`,
`compare`.`Hospital affiliation CCN 3`,
`compare`.`Hospital affiliation LBN 3`,
`compare`.`Hospital affiliation CCN 4`,
`compare`.`Hospital affiliation LBN 4`,
`compare`.`Hospital affiliation CCN 5`,
`compare`.`Hospital affiliation LBN 5`,
`compare`.`Professional accepts Medicare Assignment`,
`compare`.`Reported Quality Measures`,
`compare`.`Used electronic health records`


SELECT `himsshospital`.`Health System ID`,
`himsshospital`.`Health System`,
`himsshospital`.`Health System ID2`,
`himsshospital`.`CCN1`,
`himsshospital`.`Organization Unique Id`,
`himsshospital`.`Organization`,
`himsshospital`.`Organization Primary Service`,
`himsshospital`.`CBSA`,
`himsshospital`.`Address`,
`himsshospital`.`City`,
`himsshospital`.`State/Province`,
`himsshospital`.`Zip Code`,
`himsshospital`.`Fiscal End Date Month`,
`himsshospital`.`Hospital: Parent Organization Control`,
`himsshospital`.`Hospital: Organization Control`,
`himsshospital`.`Organization Phone`,
`himsshospital`.`Website`,
`himsshospital`.`Email Convention`,
`himsshospital`.`Date (Full Update)`,
`himsshospital`.`.`,
`himsshospital`.`Beds: Licensed`,
`himsshospital`.`Beds: Staffed`,
`himsshospital`.`EMRAM Stage (Validated)`,
`himsshospital`.`ER Visits`,
`himsshospital`.`Net Patient Revenues`,
`himsshospital`.`Operating Expense`,
`himsshospital`.`Outpatient Visits`,
`himsshospital`.`Practice: Physicians`,
`himsshospital`.`Admissions`,
`himsshospital`.`Births`,
`himsshospital`.`Cardiology Studies`,
`himsshospital`.`Hospital Physicians: Total`,
`himsshospital`.`Operating Rooms`,
`himsshospital`.`Radiology Studies`,
`himsshospital`.`Total Employees`,
`himsshospital`.`Total Inpatient Revenue`
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be that merge is an alis  for  join  betwwen tbl_names.compare and tbl_names.himsshospital then you should use different table folumn for each side
(not the same table column  tbl_names.CCN1=tbl_names.CCN1 for both side)

```
   use physician_compare;

   select tbl_names.CCN1
   from tbl_names.compare and 
   inner join tbl_names.himsshospital
   on tbl_names.CCN1=himsshospital.CCN1;
```